# azurerm_virtual_machine_extension - ArtifactVersionNotFound

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to add an azurerm_virtual_machine_extension resource to an already existing VM resource:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vm-bootstrap" {
 count = "1"
 name                 = "bootstrap"
 virtual_machine_id = ...
 publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
 type                 = "CustomScript"
 type_handler_version = "2.1"
 auto_upgrade_minor_version = "false"

 settings = <<SETTINGS
   {

      "script": "${filebase64("bootstrap.sh")}"

   }
SETTINGS
}
```

Running terraform apply returns with the following error:

> Error: compute.VirtualMachineExtensionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request:
> StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: Code="ArtifactVersionNotFound" Message="No version found in
> the artifact repository that satisfies the requested version '2.1' for VM extension with
> publisher 'Microsoft.Azure.Extensions' and type 'CustomScript'."

Though it looks like the VM extenson exists:

```
az vm extension image list-versions -n CustomScript --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions --lo
cation westeurope --query "[].name" -o tsv | sort -u
2.0.0
2.0.1
2.0.2
2.0.3
2.0.4
2.0.5
2.0.6
2.0.7
2.1.1
2.1.2
2.1.3
2.1.6
```

Terraform v1.0.11,

azure-cli: "2.30.0",

azure-cli-core: "2.30.0",

azure-cli-telemetry: "1.0.6",

"extensions": {}

Can you please advise?

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I use multiple `azurerm_virtual_machine_extension`s. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I merged both the `azurerm_virtual_machine_extension`s into a single one so I no longer have this issue.

Comment: I am also receiving the same issue, but I cannot add my scripts to one extension, as one extension is a dependency for another terraform resource and the other extension has a dependency for said resource to be created before the script to be run.

Can 2 VM custom script extension be applied to the same VM without receiving this error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by a miss match of the VM extensions versions, if you would try to specify always the `"latest"` instead of a specific one it would fix the issue. So it did in my case.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see version "2.1" in that list. Did you try 2.1.1?